# Pages: Is point in custom object with only one control handle possible?

Tags: pages, iwork

In Pages, I notice with a rounded rectangle if you make it editable and click on any of the points, they all seem to have only one "control handle". Normally there are always two. Is there really only one control handle on those points, or does it just look that way? Assuming there is indeed only one control handle, how can I do that too?

Answer (score 1):

If the handle you are speaking about is the little blue dot used to adjust the roundness of the corners of a rounded rectangle, then yes, there is only one.

(I am assuming the above assumption is true)

To use this handle, simply grab it with the pointer, and drag it. Depending on the object, it will do one of a few things.

On a rounded rectangle; it will round all the corners to the amount set by the handle.

On a star, it will adjust the sharpness of the points. (The amount of points can be set by the slider that will appear when a star is created.)

On a speech bubble, it will where the 'speech' is originating from.

And on an arrow, it will adjust the shape of the arrowhead, making it sharper, or less sharp.